# Resize contentSize of UIScrollView with embedded view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, containers

I have a UIViewController (MasterViewController) with a UIScrollView, that has a header view on top, and a container below.

When I embed any childViewController (e.g. the EmbeddedViewController), the contentSize of the UIScrollView obviously needs to be adjusted. In order to adjust the size, I need to wait until the embedded view is layouted correctly and then set

```
scrollView.contentSize.height = embeddedViewController.tableView.contentSize.height + HeaderView.frame.height;
```

**When (in the MasterViewController) can I update the scrollView.contentSize after embedding any embeddedViewController?**

I thought I could call

```
[embeddedViewController layoutIfNeeded];
```

... right before I embed it into the masterView, but somehow the scrollView contentSize is not set correctly. Do you have any ideas or a best practice for dynamic length containerViews in UIScrollViews?

[image]

Comment: You should not add UITableView to a UIScrollView.

Comment: To the background: I want to create a paralax header view with a segmented control and use the container to display different viewcontroller for the different segmentedControlTabs. therefore i need to embed ViewControllers, such as the UITableViewController, adjust its frame to its contentSize, so that it can't scroll by itself and emded it to the container view. By doing that only the scrollView is actually scrolling. I don't see a problem with that

Comment: try to change content size in `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: changing it in `viewDidAppear` can cause a flickering, since the view is already visible to the user when resized

Comment: Try to write it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @MarkHim Could you find a solution to this? I am having the exact issue

Answer (score 1):

give `scrollview` `contentsize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,350);
}
```